# Convert an existing code from STM32F0 to Atmel SAMD21 (both are arm-based cortex-M0)

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, libraries, atmel

The existing project is running well on STM32F0. The code should be converted to Atmel SAMD21.

The code is written in Visual Studio and using the IntelliSense configuration (ARM Paths). Both projects should use the I2C interface. The package which is used is ChibiOS for STM32.

- Because I didn't write the code from scratch, Which part should I change in the code or read carefully? In other words, what is common and different in programming 2 different arms?
- Do I need to do my own bootstrap (I mean the initialization part) and linker script? What else is needed?
- Also, is there any configuration file for arm definition that I should change?
- As I should change chibiOS and add the libraries for Atmel, Which library or package is better to use for Atmel SAMD?
- Is there any idea or example that is helpful to compare between these
  2 arms?

Much appreciated for any helpful suggestion, in advance.

Comment: close to zero of the code relate to the chip is expected to port the cortex-m0 isnt really relevant thats like the language, an english math book and a english biology book are not really compatible just because they are both written in english.   none of the peripherals are expected to be compatible between the two chips.  higher level code that is not related to the chip, that might port just fine

Comment: The core is the same, some ARM _options_ may differ the peripheral set will be entirely different, as will ISR mapping and names.  All your device layer code primarily (if you don't have a distinct device layer you made your job harder.  Beyond that the question is too broad, asks for recommendations, canvasses opinion and asks multiple questions in one.  As such is not a good SO question.  "configuration file" would be specific to your tool-chain/IDE - there is no standard for such things.  I don't see how Visual Studio is relevant to the question.

Comment: There is no "the I2C interface".  Peripherals are not part of the ARM core and Atmel's I2C interface will be very different than STs..  I suggest you build it and fix what breaks and ask questions about the things you cannot fix.